# How to add app shortcuts to home screen on the Note 9

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

Whenever I go to my app drawer I tap "add to home screen" to a specific app.

Instead of adding to my home screen it creates a new page. Now I have a home screen and an extra page with only one app and lots of space.

How can I go to my app drawer, add an app to my home screen and avoid this problem? Below is my home screen before adding a new shortcut. It should normally add on top of these apps but instead it just creates a page to the right with the app by itself.

[image: This is my current home screen.]

Answer (score 6):

First, check if your time and weather widget are taking too much space.

To check: long press on that particular widget and you will see how much of space it is taking.

[image: IMG:]

If you are using two different widgets for time and weather, it's recommended to use one by choosing it from:

- Tap *Widgets* from lower settings appearing on your screen,
- Right swipe widgets to see more,
- Choose *Weather* from widgets and choose widget as I am using in above pic, and it uses less space.

You can also change your *App screen grid* by going to *Home Screen Settings* on the lower right of the screen (as appears in your uploaded picture).

Now, choose from menu.

[image: IMG:]

To add new shortcuts it is very useful that you do it by long pressing on any app from App drawer, dragging it and releasing it whereever you want to place that app.

Note: you can only put apps on the blank space of your Home Screen. To check space you have to long press widgets (that are on your home screen, such as Clock, Weather widget, Google Search, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of choosing "Add to Home Screen" simply keep holding the app you wish to create a shortcut for and it will not make a new screen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings, it might throw it onto a new page by default. Or you could circumvent it by putting them all onto one page and deleting the extra page that it creates.

Comment: Where exactly in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had that too. 
Problem is that the little weather report on top right of your screen is actually taking up the whole space.  There is no more room for icons.
Double tap or long press - I forget,  the weather section and you'll see that you can crop it smaller.
Another row or two of icons will then fit on your hone screen.
Good luck to all.